Issue with Parallel Testing: CSV Data Merging in Web Automation
I’m currently working on automating a login page using parallel testing, and I’ve encountered a significant issue that I need help with.
I’m utilizing two different CSV files located at different paths for input data, and I’ve set up my test to run in parallel with a thread count of 2 using the tag parallel="tests". To facilitate reading from the CSV files, I created a CSVDataProvider class, and I have a separate class, FilePath, that retrieves the paths for these CSV files from an XML configuration.
The problem arises during execution: both web browsers open, but the data from both CSV files is merging into a single browser instance. For example, during one execution, the username from one CSV file and the password from the other file are being entered in the same browser, while the other browser remains empty. In subsequent executions, the data entry seems to swap between the browsers.
Here’s a brief overview of my setup:
Two CSV files with user credentials
Parallel testing configuration with a thread count of 2
Data provider reads data based on file paths provided in the XML file
Could anyone provide guidance on how to ensure that each browser instance receives data from its corresponding CSV file without any overlap? I appreciate any insights or suggestions!
I’ve implemented a CSVDataProvider class to read data from two separate CSV files, and I expected each browser instance to receive its respective data without any overlap. However, I’m encountering issues where both instances seem to share the data, leading to incorrect username and password entries.
I was expecting each browser to operate independently, allowing for proper parallel execution, but this is not happening.
If anyone has faced a similar issue or has suggestions on how to isolate the data for each thread, I’d greatly appreciate your input!
